# EasyMock: AssertionError on comparing object with its clone

Tags: java, testng, easymock

I'm getting such AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call ICustomerDAO.getVersionStamps(-1, ["CustomerData", "UserData"], EasyMock for interface java.sql.Connection):
    ICustomerDAO.getVersionStamps(-1, ["CustomerData", "UserData"], EasyMock for interface java.sql.Connection): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.getVersionStamps(Unknown Source)
    at com.mgmt.ConfigClient.getRequestedVersions(ConfigClient.java:200)
    at com.mgmt.ConfigClientTest.testGetRequestedVersions(ConfigClientTest.java:329)
```

Here's the test code:

```
@Test
public void testGetRequestedVersions() {
    ConfigClient client = new ConfigClient();
    client.dao = EasyMock.createStrictMock(ICustomerDAO.class);
    Connection connection = EasyMock.createStrictMock(Connection.class);
    long[] versions = {34, 12};
    EasyMock.expect(client.dao.getVersionStamps(-1, ConfigFilesRegenTask.getRequestedVersions(), connection)).andReturn(versions);
    EasyMock.replay(client.dao);
    ConfigToken token = client.getRequestedVersions(connection);
    EasyMock.verify(client.dao);
    assertEquals("Wrong customer version", versions[0], token.getCustomerVersion());
}
```

ConfigClient class:

```
public ConfigToken getRequestedVersions(Connection connection) {
    final ConfigToken token = new ConfigToken(-1, -1);
    long[] requestedVersions = dao.getVersionStamps( -1, ConfigFilesRegenTask.getRequestedVersions(), connection);
    token.setCustomerVersion(requestedVersions[0]);
    return token;
}
```

And ConfigFilesRegenTask class contains the get method which returns **the clone** of an existing array:

```
public static String[] getRequestedVersions() {
    return REQUESTED_VERSIONS.clone();
}
```

**The assertion error occurs only when I return the `REQUESTED_VERSIONS` clone of the array.**
How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow your example, but my best guess is that you need to use the Array Equality [argument matcher](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations) instead of the default matcher, which checks .equals(), not so useful for arrays.

Try changing your expectation to:

```
EasyMock.expect(client.dao.getVersionStamps(eq(-1), aryEq(ConfigFilesRegenTask.getRequestedVersions()), eq(connection))).andReturn(versions);
```